# How to get content of tags and print in one line in beautifulsoup with python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the name, email, and phone number and print them all in one line:
this is the content of `mydivs`

```
<div class="card-name"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=9dfe">Mike <b>Denis</b></a></div>
<div class="activity-value">mdniz@gmail.com</div>
<div class="activity-value">(233) 333-9814</div>
<div class="card-name"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=78f3">Sami <b>Baney</b></a></div>
<div class="activity-value">sadt@gmail.com</div>
<div class="activity-value">(123) 763-2322</div>
```

I want to get the output to look like this:

```
Mike Denis, mdniz@gmail.com, (233) 333-9814
Sami Baney, sadt@gmail.com, (123) 763-2322
```

The closest I have been able to get is the above code:

```
mydivs = soup.find_all('div', [ 'card-name', 'activity-value'])
for div in mydivs:
    print (div)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html_doc = '''
<div class="card-name"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=9dfe">Mike <b>Denis</b></a></div>
<div class="activity-value">mdniz@gmail.com</div>
<div class="activity-value">(233) 333-9814</div>
<div class="card-name"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=78f3">Sami <b>Baney</b></a></div>
<div class="activity-value">sadt@gmail.com</div>
<div class="activity-value">(123) 763-2322</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.find_all('div', [ 'card-name', 'activity-value'])
st=''
for div in mydivs:
    if re.search('^\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)', div.text):
        st+=f'{div.text}\n'
    else:
        st+=f'{div.text}, '
        
print(st)
```

Output:

```
Mike Denis, mdniz@gmail.com, (233) 333-9814
Sami Baney, sadt@gmail.com, (123) 763-2322
```

Answer (score 1):

If your divs follows the structure you have in question -> one `<div class="card-name">` followed by two `<div class="activity-value">`, then you can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="card-name"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=9dfe">Mike <b>Denis</b></a></div>
<div class="activity-value">mdniz@gmail.com</div>
<div class="activity-value">(233) 333-9814</div>
<div class="card-name"><a href="contact.php?leaduuid=78f3">Sami <b>Baney</b></a></div>
<div class="activity-value">sadt@gmail.com</div>
<div class="activity-value">(123) 763-2322</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.select('.card-name, .activity-value')
for name, email, phone in zip(divs[::3], divs[1::3], divs[2::3]):
    print('Name: {}\tE-Mail: {}\t Phone: {}'.format(name.text, email.text, phone.text))
```

Prints:

```
Name: Mike Denis    E-Mail: mdniz@gmail.com  Phone: (233) 333-9814
Name: Sami Baney    E-Mail: sadt@gmail.com   Phone: (123) 763-2322
```